# Composer Command not found after installing Homestaed

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to php and Laravel.

I have installed Homestead as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#configuring-homestead)

when I access http://homestead.app/ it is working( Im getting "No input file specified")

Then When I run # composer command inside the Homestead Directory, It says composer command not found.

How can I configure Composer to work with Homestead.

Comment: @Komal  No..But why? Homestead contains composer too?

Comment: Maybe composer not added to the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to login to ssh of Homestead virtual maschine.
If you follow official documentation, you should do following commands in your terminal(I'm suggesting git bash).

First type: `"cd ~/Homestead"`

Than: `vagrant ssh` I hope so that you are run vagrant up, if you now, do that.

After all that you just cd into your project and run composer.